# How to use html tags in sweet alert

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
var text += '<b>Hii This is Error<b>';
swal("Required", text, "error");
```

how to use html coding in Bootstrap Sweet alert plugin.

In the above code i have to write for **A error message!** to display in sweetalert. but while using html tags in text variable it takes as string,
and same string can be display in the sweetalert it can't convert in the html tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `html:true` for showing HTML content like,

```
swal({
  title: "Required",
  text: "<b>Hii This is Error<b>",
  html: true, // add this if you want to show HTML
  type: "error" // type can be error/warning/success
});
```

Read [Sweetalert configuration](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

Comment: Thank you... for the solution

Comment: If works!! Then, mark it as answer, so that it can help other SO users.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
swal({   
    title: "Error",  
    text: '<b>Hii This is Error<b>',
    html: true 
});
```

[Sweet alert documentation](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Answer (score 0):

```
swal({
title: "Required",
text: "<b>Please fill the required fields</b>",
html: true,
type: "error"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In SweetAlert 2.0 you can't use html tag,
they have mentioned that in their [guide](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#upgrading-from-1x).

The way you can do this by SweetAlert 2.0 that I have used and it worked for me is to create and pass the html as content object to swal[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747702/1889652) or the example below.

HTML content

```
var htmlContent = document.createElement("div");
htmlContent.innerHTML = "Create your html the way you want just as usual in 
<strong>JavaScript</strong> code.";
```

The swal

```
swal({
    title: "You did it.",
    content: htmlContent,
    icon: "warning",
    ...
})
```