# Pass HTML code as text of sweet alert

Tags: sweetalert

I am using [this](https://sweetalert.js.org/) in my application. I would like to use sweet alert like below.

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You are going to delete <b>"+ name +"</b> address. ",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
   })
```

But it now working. It is displaying HTML code. Thanks.

**Update**

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838965/sweet-alert-display-html-code-in-text) question, but this question is about [sweet alert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io). My question is about [sweet alert](https://sweetalert.js.org) . Both are sweet alert but both are not same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Elnoor has mentioned you can try to use html, but I had a problem in SWAL2 with it so I have used the innerHTML. Like :

```
 var myhtml = document.createElement("div");
 myhtml.innerHTML = "You are going to delete <b>"+ name +"</b> address. ";
```

And then put it in your content in swal like :

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    content: myhtml,
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
   })
```

Mark that i changed `text` tag to `content` tag.

Answer (score 8):

**Sweet Alert 2:**
Instead of `text` use `html`. 
For more check [here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#custom-html).

**Sweet Alert:** In older version of sweet alert they don't use `html` object any more, instead you can use `content` object as shown [here](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#content). And in your case you can create an element then embed your html inside that element and add it to swal's content object like below. ([Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ao7qL1fs/8/))

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = "Hello <br> <strong>World<strong> ! <hr>";

swal({
  content: elem,
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Elnoor. But your solution is for https://sweetalert2.github.io. I need solution for https://sweetalert.js.org. Thanks.

Comment: sorry friend, i have missed that part of your question. You answer is exactly what @SupremeDEV  explained  here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747702/5435780